# Error Code 1 in Python trying a Rock Paper Scissor

Tags: python, program-entry-point, exit-code

I'm learning Python through an online course and there's this Rock Paper Scissors I've been writing through the course, but as I finish with the check_for_winning_throw part, four errors come out followed by "Process finished with exit code 1". I've tried rewriting the variables for every throw, but they are the same, checking every line but I can't find the error.

```
import random

rolls = {
    'rock': {
        'defeats': ['scissors'],
        'defeated_by': ['paper']
    },
    'paper': {
        'defeats': ['rock'],
        'defeated_by': ['scissors'],
    },
    'scissors': {
        'defeats': ['paper'],
        'defeated_by': ['rock'],
    },
}


def main():
    show_header()
    play_game("You", "Computer")


def show_header():
    print("---------------------------")
    print(" Rock Paper Scissors v2")
    print("  Data Structure Edition ")
    print("---------------------------")


def play_game(player_1, player_2):
    rounds = 3
    wins_p1 = 0
    wins_p2 = 0

    roll_names = list(rolls.keys())

    while wins_p1 < rounds and wins_p2 < rounds:
        roll1 = get_roll(player_1, roll_names)
        roll2 = random.choice(roll_names)

        if not roll1:
            print("Try again!")
            continue

        print(f"{player_1} roll {roll1}")
        print(f"{player_2} rolls {roll2}")

        winner = check_for_winning_throw(player_1, player_2, roll1, roll2)

        if winner is None:
            print("This round was a tie!")
        else:
            print(f'{winner} takes the round!')
            if winner == player_1:
                wins_p1 += 1
            elif winner == player_2:
                wins_p2 += 1

        print(f"Score is {player_1}: {wins_p1} and {player_2}: {wins_p2}.")
        print()

    if wins_p1 >= rounds:
        overall_winner = player_1
    else:
        overall_winner = player_2

    print(f"{overall_winner} wins the game!")


def check_for_winning_throw(player_1, player_2, roll1, roll2):

    winner = None
    if roll1 == roll2:
        print("The play was tied!")

    outcome = rolls.get(roll1, {})
    if roll2 in outcome.get('defeats'):
        return player_1
    elif roll2 in outcome.get('defeated_by'):
        return player_2

    return winner


def get_roll(player_name, roll_names):
    print("Available rolls:")
    for index, r in enumerate(roll_names, start=1):
        print(f"{index}. {r}")

    text = input(f"{player_name}, what is your roll? ")
    selected_index = int(text) - 1

    if selected_index < 0 or selected_index >= len(rolls):
        print(f"Sorry {player_name}, {text} is out of bounds!")
        return None

    return rolls[selected_index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the outcome:

```
---------------------------
 Rock Paper Scissors v2
  Data Structure Edition 
---------------------------
Available rolls:
1. rock
2. paper
3. scissors
You, what is your roll?
```

Here I type "1" for Rock and then this comes out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bianconiglio/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/esercizi/notepad/rpsgame.py", line 101, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Bianconiglio/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/esercizi/notepad/rpsgame.py", line 21, in main
    play_game("You", "Computer")
  File "C:/Users/Bianconiglio/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/esercizi/notepad/rpsgame.py", line 39, in play_game
    roll1 = get_roll(player_1, roll_names)
  File "C:/Users/Bianconiglio/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/esercizi/notepad/rpsgame.py", line 98, in get_roll
    return rolls[selected_index]
KeyError: 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please include the text of the error message the input that produces that error.

Comment: Your `rolls` dictionary doesn't have a key `"1"`. You can only perform lookups using keys that exist in the dictionary. In your case, `"rock"`, `"paper"` and `"scissors"` are valid keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `get_roll` function, you are returning `rolls[selected_index]` but `rolls` is a dictionnary with three keys (rock, paper, scissors), and `selected_index` is 0, 1 or 2.

Change the return value to `list(rolls.keys())[selected_index]` and you will be good !